# VBA VLOOKUP error 'Type mismatch' when working with multiple files

Tags: excel, vba, vlookup

I am trying to create a macro that will open 2 files, get an ID from the 1st file (the ID represents the K column, each element row has an ID), search it with VLOOKUP in the 2nd file, copy the values from the same row, columns W and X and paste them to the 1st file, in the columns W and X.

Here is what I have tried:

```
Dim position As String
Dim last_y As Long
Dim matrix As String
Dim w_value As Variant

Workbooks(first_file_name_without_path).Activate
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).Activate

For i = 3 To ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Rows.Count
        
        Dim test As String
        position = "K" & CStr(i)
        'tried a different approach with this variable but without success'
        test = Trim(ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range(position))
        
        
        Workbooks(second_file_name_without_path).Activate
        ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).Activate
        
        last_y = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Rows.Count
        matrix = "K" & "3" & ":W" & CStr(last_y)
        'MsgBox (matrix)'
        w_value = Application.VLookup(ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(i, "K"), ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range(matrix), 23, False)
        'Error here, further code will be added later'
        MsgBox (w_value)
Next i
```

I have checked already most of the posts that exist and I cannot find my mistake. I am completely lost.

Comment: Please, try declaring `w_value` `As String`.

Comment: Doing what I suggested, does the error move to the above code line?

Comment: Nope. The solution that FunThomas provided solved the problem.

Comment: Do you mean, you made what I suggested and the same error remained on the same code line? I only supposed that 'Vlookup' returns an error and a `Variant` variable also accepted it, but `MsgBox` doesn't. It should be an error diagnose method...

Comment: Aah, I understood now what you meant. In the beginning, the `w_value` was a String but I got some other error and I have decided to make it a Variant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `VLookup` will always return an Error because you ask to get the 23rd column of a Range that has only 13 columns (K:W). If you want to return the value of column W, you need 13 as third parameter (because the column W is the 13th column of the range).
The type mismatch you see comes from the `MsgBox`-command because `w_value` contains `Error 2023`, and that is not a string but a special data type (that cannot be used as parameter to `MsgBox`)

However, you have more problems with your code, and the main reason is that you are using `ActiveWorksheet` and `Activate`. Your Vlookup will not search for the value of your first sheet in the second sheet because you search for `ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(i, "K")` but have already activated the second sheet.

In almost all cases when you program VBA, you don't need to use `activate` and `select`, and you should avoid using `ActiveSheet` and `Selection`. Read [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba) for more information

I have also replaced the usage of `UsedRange` because it is not always reliable. See [Error in finding last used cell in Excel with VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/error-in-finding-last-used-cell-in-excel-with-vba)

Have a look to the following code:

```
Dim searchRange As Range
With Workbooks(second_file_name_without_path).Sheets(1)
    Dim last_y As Long
    last_y = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "K").End(xlUp).row
    Set searchRange = .Range("K3:W" & last_y)
End With
  
With Workbooks(first_file_name_without_path).Sheets(1)

    Dim lastRow As Long
    lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "K").End(xlUp).row

    Dim i As Long
    For i = 3 To lastRow
        Dim searchVal
        searchVal = .Cells(i, "K")
        Dim w_value As Variant
        w_value = Application.VLookup(searchVal, searchRange, 13, False)
        If IsError(w_value) Then
            MsgBox "An error occurred looking for " & searchVal & vbCrLf & CStr(w_value)
        Else
            MsgBox w_value
        End If
    Next i
End With
```